# Is it possible to use a registry look up in Toothpick 3.x?

Tags: toothpick-di

Toothpick is working great for us on Android, but the required proguard / R8 rules mean that classes using injection cannot be obfuscated to the degree we need. It seems like the reason the rules are required is for the `Class.forName` calls in the `FactoryLocator` and `MemberInjectorLocator` classes. The wiki mentions a config option `disableReflection` which could help, but it seems like this was discontinued after TP 1.x.

I'm hoping to play around with the code and perhaps re-add a registry generator. But before I do - have I correctly identified the reason the proguard / R8 rules are required, or have I missed some other subtlety in the code? Was there a specific reason the registry approach was dropped after 1.x? Did the original registry approach just generate code which explicitly mapped a class to its factory / member injector, or did it take a different approach?

Thanks,
John